# sftp how to get the folder size and total count of files in a folder

Tags: sftp

want to know the folder size and also the count of total files in the folder over sftp.

Even using lfpt is fine.

I know in linux we can use du -sh for getting folder size.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use `sshfs` to mount the directory of interest locally, and then use the standard Linux tools as you already mentioned.

Comment: I tried that, but when i try du -sh it exists

Comment: äh, what does exit? Could you edit your question to include what *exactly* you've tried.